# What does the phrase "in order to" function as?

Tags: grammar

I was wondering what function the phrase "in order to" has. 
I have thought for quite a while that it was used a a conjunction. However, I have recently seen sentences that use this phrase in other ways such as a clause or an adverb.
Is "in order to" a conjunction or an adverb or some other clause or phrase?

Comment: What possibilities have you considered, and what in particular is confusing you or leading you to the question? We can't give a really good answer without knowing those things. If you can [edit] the question to add that information it will help greatly.

Comment: I may have answered to hastily  @Matt-Gutting was right to ask for additional information and your subsequent edit is a good start. I think an example or two would also be helpful, so that we'd know what you mean when you say that you've seen phrase used as a clause or an adverb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**"In order to"** is a subordinating conjunction.  (*I.e.* a clause that follows "in order to" becomes a subordinate clause, which needs a main clause to make a complete sentence.)

"In order to" generally introduces a "final clause," which is a clause that states a purpose.

The subordinate clause introduced by "in order to" is an adverbial clause, but the phrase itself is not categorized as an adverb.

A discussion of "however," a conjunction that *can* be an adverb, may be of interest to you.  If so, take a look at [this](https://wordsphrasesclauses.wordpress.com/category/adverbs/) blog post.

References:

"In Order to" in [English Grammar Today](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/in-order-to)

"Final Clause" in [Fowler's Dictionary of Modern English Usage](https://books.google.com/books?num=10&id=AvmzBgAAQBAJ&q=%22in%20order%20to%22#v=snippet&q=%22in%20order%20to%22&f=false)

Comment: An example of your own would be helpful :-)

Comment: I know of no other 'subordinating conjunctions' that take a bare infinitive, unless you include 'so as to' etc.